# Loading image into canvas - image scaled

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, drawimage

I'm having a problem with loading image into canvas - the image is somehow scaled.

Background: I've got several canvases on my web page, I want to load images into them. When constructing, I'm not sure about the dimension, because the size depends on the screen size.

So I create div and canvas, use css to have it in the size that I want it to have and print an image onto the canvas. There would couple more things to do with the image (i.e. decide based on the ratio if I need to center it vertically or horizontally), but those are not really important at this point. The problem is that the image is rendered "zoomed".

Example: the javascript piece is here:

```
$("canvas").each(function() {
  var context = $(this)[0].getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image;

  img.src = 'http://i67.tinypic.com/n38zdv.jpg';

  $(img).load(function() {
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  });

//img will print 400 (correct, thats the width of the img)
//canvas will print based on the screen size (correct)
//img displayed in the canvas shows 300px out of 400px, it's zoomed (not correct)
  $(this).parent().append(
    'img width: '+img.width+
    ', canvas width: '+$(this).width());
});
```

I put the whole example with HTML and CSS to https://jsfiddle.net/7zdrfe58/11/.

I'm trying on Mac. Safari and Chrome work the same (i.e. with the zoom).

I would very appreciate help with this!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawImage` lets you specify the width and height of the image. You can get the canvas width like so:

```
$("canvas").each(function() {
  var canvas = this;
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image;
  img.src = 'http://i67.tinypic.com/n38zdv.jpg';

  $(img).load(function() {
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  });
});
```

Check out your working code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ucxdLsq9/

The documentation of the `drawImage` signatures can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: Great, thanks. I understand that the canvas is smaller and then extended during (re)rendering. That might explain why are the lines in the example blurry?

Comment: You haven't set your `<canvas>`'s `width` and `height` attributes. You'll see the default values by the time the image is drawn are something like 300x150. You'll have to make sure you find the right widths and heights to use in the right order...

Answer (score 0):

Give proper width and height to `drawImage`.

```
context.drawImage(this, 0, 0 ,300 ,160);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zdrfe58/13/)**